# Write to properties file inside a java Package

Tags: java, properties, fileoutputstream

How to write to properties file in a java package using java class in another package.

Here is the code for writing properties file

```
String filePath1 = "com/...../application.properties";
        File applicationProperties = new File(filePath1);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(applicationProperties);
        Date todayDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        properties.setProperty("application.database.backup.date", sdf.format(todayDate));
        properties.store(fileOutputStream, "storing index values to properties file");
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

Getting FileNotFoundException.But file is exist in this package.while reading these file get the output.

```
String filePath = "com/....../application.properties";
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        if (properties.getProperty("application.grouping.mode") != null || !properties.getProperty("application.grouping.mode").isEmpty()) {

            String lastBackupDate = properties.getProperty("application.grouping.mode");


    }
```

How to solve this Exception.

Comment: Is your `com` directory present in other directory like `src` or something?

Comment: yes.package inside src

Comment: Make sure the following 1) whether you have write permission to the file? 2) If exists whether the path given in the code above is right? keep in mind, the path given above is relative.

Comment: Store it in the **Preferences**, or when rights are problematic, user-defined Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems here, which are related. Basically, you're assuming that get because you can read from a resource, you can write to a file in the same folder structure, relative to the current directory. That's a flawed assumption because:

- The resources may not be on the file system as separate files to start with. For example, Java applications are usually packaged up into jar files. The classloader knows how to read resources from a jar file, but the folder structure isn't present on disk
- Even if the files *are* on disk as separate files in the right folder structure, they may not be rooted in the process's working directory. For example:

  ```
  # Running in /home/jon/Documents
  $ java -cp /home/jon/java/bin com.foo.bar.SomeApplication
  ```

Here `SomeApplication.class` would be in `/home/jon/java/bin/com/foo/bar`, but `new File("com/foo/bar/something.properties")` would refer to `/home/jon/Documents/com/foo/bar/something.properties`.

Finally, even if you *were* trying to write to the right place, you may not have write access - very often the binaries for applications are stored in read-only directories, with the reasonable justification that the code and read-only application data should be separated from the application's changing state. Aside from anything else, this makes updates/repairs much easier - just blow away the old version's directory, knowing that you won't have lost any user data.

Your context isn't clear, but I would suggest that you find some appropriate way of passing a filename to the application, and write to that and read from it where you need to.

Comment: @User123: Of what? You haven't even told us what kind of application this is. All I'm suggesting is that you provide your app with a filename explicitly... that could be through command line parameters, servlet configuration, whatever it is...

Comment: @User123: That doesn't tell us anything. Web application? Console application? Swing? How are you starting it? What does it do? Do you have any other configuration files?

Comment: It is Swing application.I want to update property value each login to the application

Comment: @User123: Have you considered using the preferences API instead? It sounds like that may be more suitable. (It's been a long time since I've used it, admittedly.) But either way, think about separating your application code and read-only data from the data that changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your property file is in class path. after that you should be able to load it as

```
String filePath = "/application.properties";
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
```

Comment: can load properties but cannot write to properties

Answer (score 0):

Your `com` is in the `src` directory. So your file path must be `src/com/.....`. It must start with `src/` and not `com/`